# Deriving Burger's equation for energy eigenvalues in $T\bar T$-deformed theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, integrable-systems

When doing $T \bar T$-deformation to 2d CFTs, it is interesting to ask how the original energy spectrum is shifted throughout the procedure. This is done as follows.

As mentioned in several papers/reviews: [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401146),[2](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.nuclphysb.2016.12.014),[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.13376)], the factorisation property of $T \bar T$ for a deformed CFT on a cylinder with radius $R$ reads (equation (35) in [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401146)])
$$
\langle n|T \bar T|n\rangle = -\pi^2 \left(\langle n|T_{yy}|n\rangle\langle n|T_{xx}|n\rangle - \langle n|T_{xy}|n\rangle \langle n|T_{xy}|n\rangle \right).\tag{35}
$$
Upon identifying
$$
\langle n|T_{yy}|n\rangle = - \frac{1}{R} E_n(R;\alpha), \quad \langle n|T_{xx}|n\rangle = - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d R}E_n(R;\alpha), \quad \langle n|T_{xy}|n\rangle = \frac{\mathrm i}{R} P_n(R), \tag{36-37}
$$
where $E_n(R;\alpha), P_n(R)$ are the energy/momentum eigenvalues of state $|n\rangle$ with deformation parameter $\alpha$, respectively, we get
$$
\langle n| T \bar T|n\rangle = - \frac{\pi^2}{R}\left(E_n(R;\alpha) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dR} E_n(R;\alpha) + \frac{1}{R} P_n^2(R)\right).\tag{38}
$$

The next step, **which I don't understand properly**, is to interpret
$$
\langle n| T \bar T|n\rangle \stackrel{!}{=} \frac{\pi^2}{R} \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} E_n(R;\alpha),
$$
which gives the [Burgers' equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation), describing the shift in energy spectrum.

I don't quite understand the last step. Could anyone elaborate why one can identify the expectation value of $T \bar T$ with $\partial E_n/\partial \alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question.

1. Refs. 1-3 are considering a scalar field theory where the 1+1D world-sheet (WS) is a cylinder with circumference $\ell$. The Lagrangian density is $T\bar{T}$-deformed
   $$ \frac{\partial {\cal L}_{(\alpha)}}{\partial \alpha}
   ~=~ \det(T^{\mu\nu}_{(\alpha)}), \tag{A}$$
   cf. Ref. 2 eq. (5.1) and Ref. 3 eq. (2.1). Here $\alpha$ is a deformation parameter.
   The [canonical SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Canonical_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) is symmetric$^1$
   $$T^{\mu\nu}_{(\alpha)}
   ~=~ {\cal P}^{\mu}_{(\alpha)}\partial^{\nu}\phi 
   -g^{\mu\nu}{{\cal L}_{(\alpha)}}
   ~=~(\mu\leftrightarrow \nu),\tag{B} $$
   where the canonical momentum density is
   $$ {\cal P}^{\mu}_{(\alpha)}~:=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}_{(\alpha)}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}, \qquad 
   {\cal P}^{\mu}_{(\alpha=0)}~=~\partial^{\mu}\phi.\tag{C}$$
2. The total energy and momentum are
   $$\begin{align} E_{(\alpha)}(\ell)~:=~&\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~T^{00}_{(\alpha)}
   ~\stackrel{(B)+(E)}{=}~P_{(\alpha)}(\ell)-\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~{\cal L}_{(\alpha)}, \tag{D}\cr 
   P_{(\alpha)}(\ell)~:=~&\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~T^{01}_{(\alpha)}
   ~\stackrel{(B)}{=}~\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~{\cal P}^{1}_{(\alpha)}\partial_0\phi.\tag{E}\end{align}$$
   Since $\langle F_{\rm ext} \rangle \delta\ell =$ external work  = change in mechanical energy
   $$-\frac{1}{\ell}\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~T^{11}_{(\alpha)}
   ~\stackrel{(D)}{=}~\frac{dE_{(\alpha)}(\ell)}{d\ell},\tag{F}$$
   cf. Ref. 1 eq. (36) and Ref. 3 eq. (3.23).
3. From periodicity of the cylinder the generator of translation must satisfy
   $$\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}\ell \hat{P}_{(\alpha)}(\ell)\right)~=~\hat{\bf 1}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad {\rm Spec}(\hat{P}_{(\alpha)}(\ell))~\subseteq~\frac{2\pi\hbar}{\ell}\mathbb{Z}\tag{G}$$
   at the quantum-level. We conclude that the momentum is quantized and remains undeformed
   $$ \frac{\partial P_{(\alpha)}(\ell)}{\partial \alpha}~\stackrel{(G)}{=}~0,\tag{H}$$
   cf. Ref. 3 below eq. (3.27).
4. Altogether, we obtain OP's sought-for equation
   $$-\frac{\partial E_{(\alpha)}(\ell)}{\partial \alpha}
   ~\stackrel{(A)+(D)+(H)}{=}~\int_0^{\ell}\! dx~ \det(T^{\mu\nu}_{(\alpha)}),\tag{I}$$
   cf. Ref. 1 eq. (36) and Ref. 3 eq. (3.24).
5. For a proof of the factorizatization of $\langle n|\det(\hat{T}^{\mu\nu}_{(\alpha)})|n\rangle $ into diagonal matrix elements of the SEM tensor, see section 3.2 in Ref. 3.

References:

1. A.B. Zamolodchikov, [arXiv:hep-th/0401146](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401146); eqs. (36)-(41).
2. F.A. Smirnov & A.B. Zamolodchikov, [arXiv:1608.05499](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05499); section 5.
3. Y. Jiang, [arXiv:1904.13376](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.13376); section 3.3.

--

$^1$ *Conventions.* We choose the WS metric to be $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$ and the speed of light $c=1$.