# Spatial component of energy-mometum tensor for the 2D infinite cylinder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, integrable-systems

I am reading [Zamolodchikov's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0401146) and a question arises, so I would like to ask it.

In this paper, he considers QFT on a 2D infinite cylinder where spatial direction is compactified on a circle of circumference $R$, $$(\mathrm{x},\mathrm{y})\sim (\mathrm{x}+R,\mathrm{y}),\tag{p.9}$$ and time coordinate $\mathrm{y}$ is taken to be Euclidean. He argues that by the very meaning of energy-momentum tensor following equations hold:
\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
&\langle n|T_{\mathrm{yy}}|n\rangle=-\frac{1}{R}E_{n}(R),&&
\langle n|T_{\mathrm{xx}}|n\rangle =-\frac{d}{dR}E_{n}(R),&&
\langle n|T_{\mathrm{xy}}|n\rangle =\frac{i}{R}P_{n}(R).
\end{aligned}\tag{36/37}
\end{align}
I know what the first and third equations mean, but I don't understand why the second one holds. I would like to know why the $\mathrm{xx}$ component of the energy-momentum tensor is related to the derivative of the energy with respect to the spatial size.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/767035/2451 where eqs. (36/37) are explained.

Comment: While my question is about $\langle n|T_{\mathrm{xx}}|n\rangle =-\frac{d}{dR} E_{n}(R)$, the question you presented is about $\langle n|T\bar{T}|n\rangle =\frac{\pi^{2}}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}E_{n}(R,\alpha)$, which is a different question.

Comment: Hi sakata. Check eq. (F) in my answer there.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand a little better now.